# Induction—allowed to use n = k - 1 for induction step?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, solution-verification

I was just wondering about trying to prove this statement: for all negative integers $n$, $(-2) + (-4) + \dots (2n) = -n^2 + n$.

In my Induction Hypothesis I assume that the claim holds for some negative integer $k \leq -1$. Since I'm proving for negative integers, am I allowed in my induction step to try and prove that the claim holds when $n = k-1$? In the past I've always been using $n = k + 1$ for my induction step, so I'm not sure if this approach is valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this approach is valid. However, it would be simpler to perform induction on $2 + 4 + \cdots + 2n$ instead, and then multiply by $-1$.

Another type of induction that does not use $n = k+1$ is when you prove that $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ hold, then perform induction on $n = k+2$. This is called double induction. There is a great resource on this [here](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Resource/AL/Different%20kinds%20of%20Mathematical%20Induction.pdf) with many other types of induction.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? If you can show that $\forall n \le -1:P(n) \implies P(n-1)$, then you are done.